# Python Selenium Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I tried to run this code in python but got the following error:

TypeError: **main**.checkout() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebDriver

```js
def checkout():
  browser.get("https://google.com")

for i in range(5):
browserThread = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome()))
browserThread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is saying that it's expecting a `args` to be a tuple. You should also add your argument in checkout and reference `browser` that way.

I think you'd set `args` like this:

`... args=((webdriver.Chrome()),)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def checkout(browser, url):
    browser.get(url)

for i in range(5):
    browserThread = threading.Thread(target=checkout, args=(webdriver.Chrome(), 'https://www.google.com'))
    browserThread.start()
```

And ensure executable file 'Chrome driver' is available in any PATH.